# How to wait for main Thread until asynchronous methods will finish?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, java-8

I have **Service.class** with `start()` method:

```
public void start()  {  
    for (int i = 0; i < companiesList.size(); i++) {
        asychronous.someAsynchronous(...);
    }
    log.info("Start method has finished");
}
```

I have **Asynchronous.class** with `someAsynchronous()` method:

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Void> someAsynchronous(some_parameters) {
    //do some stuff
    return null;
}
```

The `log.info()` shows up before `someAsynchronous()` methods has finished.
How to force it to wait for `log.info()` until `someSynchronous()` methods in loop will finish? Btw: Asynchronous threads are still running after finishing loop.

Comment: Of course it shows up before, that's the whole point of the methods being executed asynchronously. Are you sure the method is supposed to be async at all? But you can still get the `CompletableFuture`s and wait for those.

Comment: @Kayaman They are executed in new seperate threads thats fine, but I want to let them to finish and then let main Thread continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CompletableFuture<Void>` calls are requested to be executed but after all of them start in separate threads, the for-loop finishes and the log is printed even before any of them finished. This is the advantage of the asynchronous processing - you don't care about their results and how much time they took to execute.

To achieve you want, you have to periodically check whether **all** of them are finished before you proceed to the log outoput.

```
// Adds executions to the List
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < companiesList.size(); i++) {
    futures.add(asychronous.someAsynchronous(...));
}

// Periodical check
Iterator<CompletableFuture<Void>> iterator = futures.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = iterator.next(); // get the next one
    if (future.isDone()) {                            // if finished...
        //...                                         // ... do an action
        iterator.remove();                            // ... and remove from the Iterator
    }
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) {                        // if you reach the end
        iterator = futures.iterator();                // ... repeat the remaining Futures
    }
}

log.info("Start method has finished");
```

Note this method doesn't finish until **all** of the executions are done.

---

Edit: Thanks to *@Kayaman* who suggested using a single [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) dedicated for that replacing the whole `Iterator` logics. The `futures` must be an array:

```
// Adds executions to the List
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < companiesList.size(); i++) {
    futures.add(asychronous.someAsynchronous(...));
}

// Join the completion of all the threads
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();

log.info("Start method has finished");
```

Comment: Replace your iterator stuff with `CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();`. No need to spin the main thread or over-engineer an iterator.

Comment: Thank you Kayaman, it's a good hint. Multithreading is my weakness.

Comment: Yes, `CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]).join();`, it's a varargs parameter. @januszj the iterator can be replaced by that. Or `.forEach()` [if you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705981/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-wait-till-the-completable-future-threads-finish).

Comment: @Kayaman What you mean the iterator? Iterator<CompletableFuture<Void>> iterator = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]).join(); ?