# Count number of occurrences of property inside List<CompletableFuture<Name>>

Tags: java

I have the following list

```
List<CompletableFuture<Name>> myList;
```

The `Name` class contains the following properties.

```
String name;
boolean available;
```

How can I count the total number of name objects which have the available property set to true?

Comment: `myList.stream().map(CompletableFuture::get).filter(f->f.available).count()` ? Just wrap get catching InterruptedExcetion

Comment: @gdomo you can also use CompletableFuture::join, which throws unchecked exception

Answer (score 0):

You first need to wait for the completion of the `Future`s, then you could can `filter()` the ones with available set to `true` and last but not least `count()` the amount of list items left. For all of that I am using the [Java Stream API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {
    record Name(String name, boolean available){};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var input = new ArrayList<CompletableFuture<Name>>();
        input.add(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new Name("Thomas", true)));
        input.add(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new Name("John", true)));
        input.add(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new Name("Pat", false)));
        var total = input.stream()
                .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                .filter(name -> name.available)
                .count();
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
2
```

In terms of waiting for the `Future`s to complete have a look at [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705981/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-wait-till-the-completable-future-threads-finish) which discusses some of the available options and their behavior in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

### If you want a synchronous result

Getting the result synchronously is easy.

```
static int countNames(List<CompletableFuture<Name>> names) {
    int count = 0;
    for (CompletableFuture<Name> futureName: names) {
        if (futureName.join().available) { // this is where you'd get exceptions
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The only problem is that you'll get exceptions propagated to you, and you'll have to wait for every future to complete in order.

### If you want an asynchronous result

This method gives you a result that is also a `Future`, allowing you to continue a promise-like flow.

```
static Future<Integer> countNames(List<CompletableFuture<Name>> names) {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> tally = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0);
    for (CompletableFuture<Name> futureName: names) {
        tally = futureName.thenCombine(tally, (name, count) -> name.available ? count + 1 : count);
    }
    return tally;
}
```